# KM Curve with time-varying covariates ± left-truncation

Tags: r, survival

In the usual construction of a Kaplan-Meier curve in R where individuals are observed from when first at risk through to either failure or censoring, one can specify something like:

```
survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ group, data = dat)
```

Which creates separate survival curves by levels of the grouping variable, where there is a single observation period for each individual.

That's all fine, but I don't fully appreciate the following two extensions of that basic scenario:

1. The grouping variable is time-varying. Thus, there is potentially more than one row of data per individual (counting process format)
2. Additionally, delayed-entry (left-truncation) may be present where the individual comes under observation at some time past when their risk of having the event commences (counting process format with potential non-zero time1)

Both of these situations are represented using time1, time2 format in the same way (as I understand):

```
survfit(Surv(time1, time2, status) ~ group, data = dat)
```

Is the KM curve produced from this correct/meaningful given an individual may not belong uniquely to a group?

Comment: It looks like this has been answered in a similar post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473457/extended-kaplan-meier-for-time-dependent-covariates